# Unsafe permissions on homedir in Powershell Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, gnupg, gpg-agent

I am trying to run gpg command (gnupg) in a Linux Azure Function but I get this error:

```
> ERROR: gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/home/.gnupg'
```

I reduced my code to just be `gpg --list-keys` to simplify and the error persists. `gpg -?` runs fine so the command is in there.
I tried to run `gpg-agent --daemon` first but then I get the same error for gpg-agent.
All of this runs fine in Cloud Shell.
Any ideas on why or what I should do? It's fine with me if you have an Azure Functions Windows solution, I just need to run PowerShell. Thanks

Comment: PS: I tried `sudo`, `chmod` and `chown` but I cannot run those commands either.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an `Azure Function` Premium plan with Runtime Stack `.NET`.

Navigate to the `Azure Function` => `Advanced Tools` => `Go` .

Run `gpg --list-keys` command either in `SSH` or `Bash`.

[image]

- When I tried to run the same command again, I got the same permission error.

[image]

When I checked in the `home/gnupg` folder, Iam able to see the 2 created files.

```cs
cd ..
cd home/.gnupg
ls
```

[image]